# Google want YouTube video and test account credentials as part of G Suite app verification process

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-workspace

We have a product which used G Suite api for that we have done setup of project using https://console.developers.google.com/ and setup all things mentioned in below urls :
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en-GB#authorized-domains 
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865

And i have submit that for verification process.
Now Google sent me a mail like this.
[image: app-verification-mail]

Which tell us to provide YouTube link which show my app workflow and test account.
So where these all process mentioned like how-much steps it will take to complete the verification process?

Is there any documentation anywhere where all process mentioned?

Comment: Ok thats really weird i have never seen that email before.   I am going to email the team.  I know of no documentation that speaks of a requirement of seeing a application flow.

Comment: That's weird for me also, So can you double check with team and reply me asap because we are in critical phase because without verification of this we can't go ahead with our application. Thanks

Comment: I have sent off an email but this is google we are talking about they respond when they have time.    I have linked your question they may respond here.

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo for quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this email is from Google. We require the video to verify the functionality of the app and review the login process. Thank you for your suggestion on improving our documentation, we'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @nvnagr, may i know after this process how many steps will remain for complete the verification?

Comment: There are a number of checks that are being done. So it is hard to answer as I don't know what checks have been done and what is pending.

Comment: Basically i have done all things from my side and i also submitted video url along with credentials now i got this reply.

Unfortunately, the video your provided was insufficient.

Please reply back with a YouTube video link showing how users install your app, grant permissions, and utilize the scopes you are requesting, so we can experience the user sign-up flow, validate the app services, and then proceed with Verification process.

What does it mean?
Thanks